# Query execution time log, PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Objective: I have thousands of data, I want to know how to have a record of all the queries and the time it takes to complete each query.

Any suggestions what I should investigate? I've seen about pg_stat_activity. I am fully available to nurture myself, I would appreciate any documentation, since I only have basic knowledge.

PD: Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [log_min_duration_statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-MIN-DURATION-STATEMENT) setting in the postgresql.conf file that defines a minimum duration, after which the duration and statement will be logged.  If set to zero, *all* statements and durations are logged.

One should take care that using this setting does not consume too much disk space.

Comment: Thank u, i'll try, what do you think of pg_stat_statement?

Comment: I haven't used pg_stat_statement, so I don't have an opinion about it.